# Mean of 3 linkedlist and return in a linkedlist format

Tags: linked-list

guys I've been trying to solve this interview question but can get my head around it.

question- Mean of 3 linked lists and return the answer in a LinkedList format

Comment: Mean is an arithmetic average (sum of values divided by number of values). I'm guessing the question was asking for the median (a node where there are as many nodes with elements of lesser value as there are nodes with elements of greater value).

Answer (score 0):

Without any clarifications ,I am  assuming the following
1)You have 3 linked list
2)The length of each linked list is the same.
3)We create a new linkedlist that stores the mean of the corresponding three nodes.
4)We traverse the lists and save their mean in a newly created node.

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
    public:
    T data;
    Node* next;

    Node(T data) {
        next = NULL;
        this->data = data;
    }

    ~Node() {
        if (next != NULL) {
            delete next;
        }
    }
};


Node<double>* listMean(Node<int> *head1,Node<int> *head2,Node<int> *head3)
{//sentinel head node 
 Node<double> *sent= new Node<int>(0.0);
 Node<double> *curr=sent;
 while(head1!=NULL)
  { 
      double temp=(head1->data+head2->data+head3->data)/3; 
      curr->next = new Node<double>(temp);
      curr=curr->next; 
      head1=head1->next;
      head2=head2->next;
      head3=head3->next;
}
Node<double> *head=sent->next;
//delete the sentinel head to avoid memory leak 
delete(sent);
return head;
}
```